How to preserve newlines in source code in TinyMCE?
I have the following in my textarea:
<p style="white-space: pre-line;">
This is some test with a new line
here and also
here
</p>

When I render that in TinyMCE, I get the following source:
<p style="white-space: pre-line;" data-mce-style="white-space: pre-line;">This is some test with a new line here and also here</p>

How can I get TinyMCE to preserve line breaks (regular \n or \r\n, not <br> tags) in the source code?
